# How to import global css in Vue with PostCSS?

Tags: css, vue.js, postcss, postcss-loader

My **Vue** project structure: **styles** directory includes all css file.

```
src
├── assets
├── components
├── styles
│   ├── main.css
│   ├── normalize.css
│   └── variables.css
├── views
├── App.vue
├── main.ts
├── router.ts
```

The **src/styles/main.css** import other css just like:

```
@import 'normalize.css';
@import 'variables.css';
```

I want to import the `src/styles/main.css` in Vue global. That is:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import './styles/main.css';  // global
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Then I can directly use the variable defined in **variables.css** in every **.vue** component. Like:

```
<style lang="postcss" scoped>
a {
  color: $primary;  // defined in variables.css
}
</style>
```

But the `postcss-loader` failed to resolve the `$primary` variable:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js):
Syntax Error

(79:10) Could not resolve the variable "$primary" within "$primary"
```

How can I import global `main.css` so I don't need to `@import 'variables.css'` in every `.vue` compoment?

The demo repository is here: https://github.com/Jancat/vue-cli-ts-demo

Comment: I use `PostCSS` plugins and not use `sass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think PostCss does not have a variable syntax like "@variable". This rather looks like SASS or LESS.
I think you have to install a separate plugin to get such variables working with PostCSS:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-variables

PostCSS uses this syntax:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties

**EDIT:**

Ok, after some research I found this information: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/328

I am quite sure that this is also valid for postcss-custom-properties. So you will have to import the variables in each component.

Comment: I had add `postcss-advanced-variables` and it works when I `@import 'variables.css'` in every .vue component.